# run a c++ program on a webpage (html)

Tags: c++, html, captcha

I have made a captcha program using c++ and sfml. I want to run that program on a html page. How to do that?

Comment: If your program can simply generate the image on the standard output (e.g. in jpeg) you can adapt it for CGI.

Comment: I'm not sure, but think you can use `ASP.NET` with `C++/CLI` to do this..

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's not recommended to run C++ applications on the web. But if you can convert it to `CGI` codes, you can use `cgi-bin` directory, if your hosting server supports it. Core code convertion should be easy since `CGI` is `C` based but you may have problems with external libraries.

Edit: If you really want to go with C++ way, you need to create an `ActiveX` component but this will require additional permissions/certificates for the browser. I don't recommend this method.

Edit 2: Here is a link for creating ActiveX for web. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/CompleteActiveX.aspx

Edit 3: Please notice I added "ActiveX" alternative after owner of the question said "well i dont want it to upload on net. Just want to test it offline".

Comment: well i dont want it to upload on net. Just want to *test* it offline .

Comment: then you need to convert it to ActiveX as i added to my answer.

Comment: Captcha really needs to run server-side.  You don't need ActiveX for that.

Comment: @Will Bickford: I think you didn't notice that I edited my message after zedai commented like "well i dont want it to upload on net. Just want to test it offline"

Comment: Hmm normally I would still setup a local web server.

Comment: Yes, this is why I ended it up like "I don't recommend this method." ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the [Wikiepdia page on web application frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework), and particular the [Wikipedia comparison of these web application frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks) -- and while C++ is not the most common language for these tasks, it can in fact be done.